# Angular JS Unit Testing $httpBackend spec has no expectations

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I have a unit test in which the only expectation is that a http call was made.  I use $httpBackend.expect() for this.  This works fine, and the unit test fails if this http request is not made (which is good), and passes if the http request is made.

The problem is that even thought it passes, Jasmine spec runner shows "SPEC HAS NO EXPECTATIONS" for this unit test, which makes me think I am not using the recommended way to test that a http call was made.  How do I avoid seeing this message?

Example test:

```
it('should call sessioncheck api', function () {
    inject(function ($injector, SessionTrackerService) {
        $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');

        var mockResponse = { IsAuthenticated: true, secondsRemaining: 100 };
        $httpBackend.expect('GET', 'API/authentication/sessioncheck')
            .respond(200, mockResponse);

        SessionTrackerService.Start();

        jasmine.clock().tick(30001);
        $httpBackend.flush();
    });
});
```

Comment: Could add your code here just to illustrate it a bit? It could be some tiny mistake elsewhere

Comment: I tried to recreate the situation here: http://plnkr.co/edit/aGbBudhd3hYGa98g4V12?p=preview . But i did not get that warning, can you check for differences?

Comment: Looks like this is because I'm using Jasmine 2.1.1. Here's a new plunkr (I couldn't find a cdn for Jasmine 2.1.1) http://plnkr.co/edit/3AZotN?p=preview

Comment: Does .whenGET() differs from .expect('GET') in any way?

Comment: expect throws an error if the call was never made.  Among other differences. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend#request-expectations-vs-backend-definitions

Comment: I have the same problem. As a (really ugly) workaround I add `expect(true).toBeTruthy()` to every test just to remove this warning.

Comment: I'm using something a bit less ugly: `expect('Suppress SPEC HAS NO EXPECTATIONS').toBeDefined();`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I wrap the call to flush as follows:

```
expect($httpBackend.flush).not.toThrow();
```

I prefer this approach because the test code clearly states what 'should' happen when flush is called. For example:

```
it('should call expected url', inject(function($http) {
    // arrange
    $httpBackend.expectGET('http://localhost/1').respond(200);

    // act
    $http.get('http://localhost/1');

    // assert
    expect($httpBackend.flush).not.toThrow();

}));
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to remove jasmine.clock().tick(30001);

It's excess in this code if you don't have timeout inside SessionTrackerService.Start method